# Spice Simulator Error: Why "Inductor loop" is bad?

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, spice

(I now making a tutorial about basics of circuit technology. The below is not about a specific circuit but general theory)

I have used Spice simulator many years and I know "Voltage and/or Inductor Loop" cause error and I did a lot of things in simulation tasks. To think about the reason for that
"Voltage loop" can be understood easily as an NG but still I can't explain why "inductor loop" is bad.

How you guys explain this?

Comment: The problem is in the fact that the ideal inductor will have zero ohmic resistance. Thus, it will create a short circuit in a DC circuit.

Comment: @G36 Can't the nodes of looped inductors be assumed as same potential nodes in DC analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the loop between two parallel zero-resistance inductors.  Or an inductor and voltage source.  The current in this loop is undefined: it can be anything in general, and has no effect on the surrounding circuit, no interaction with it: it is a free variable.

SPICE engines formulate the circuit as a matrix, with columns representing node voltages, and the matrix elements representing currents between them.  The system of equations is solved by inverting the matrix, solving for all currents and voltages simultaneously.

A free variable in a system of linear equations, means that system cannot be uniquely solved.  Inverting such a matrix is akin to dividing by zero.  We call such a matrix *singular*.  Hence the error in many SPICE engines is "singular matrix".

The current in such a loop becomes definite (and dependent on the surrounding  circuit, and solvable within it) when some series resistance is added.

This also applies to series capacitors, the *voltage* between which is undefined in precisely this way, and becomes definite when shunt resistance is included.  (This is a common enough approach that a global `RSHUNT` parameter is usually available, and may have a default value that masks this underlying design issue.  The same is not true for parallel inductors, which you need to include some loop resistance in.)